# How to call an executable from the context menu and pass it the file name and location as arguments?

Tags: nautilus, context-menu, nautilus-actions

I need to read text files, extract data from them, and then write another file with that information, so I coded a simple program to do it in python. Now I would like to call that program from the context menu and pass it the location of the file and its name as arguments. I have no idea how to do that.

I know that it is possible to edit the context menu with Nautilus Actions but I don't know how to pass the file's path and name.

Also, if there's an option that uses only shell script commands, that would be preferred over using Nautilus Actions.

Comment: Refer to [NautilusScriptsHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) in the wiki

Answer (score 0):

Use `%f` (or `%F`) in the parameters of the command in Nautilus Actions to pass selected filenames as arguments:

[image]

The command in Nautilus Actions can be a simple shell script, so I'm not sure what you mean by "if there's an option that uses only shell script commands, that would be preferred over using Nautilus Actions".